# Update Panel Not working For Checkbox

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, updatepanel

In the below code Changing **asyncPostBackTrigger** to **PostBackTrigger** causing the entirepage postback.

But the below code is not at all doing anything when we use the trigger as **asyncPostBackTrigger**.

Any suggestions about what I am doing wrong??

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
            <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel_1" >

                <ContentTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNotKnown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
                                    Text="(Not Known)" OnCheckedChanged="chkNotKnown_CheckedChanged"/>
                </ContentTemplate>

                <Triggers>
                    <asp:asyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="chkNotKnown"/>
                </Triggers>

            </asp:UpdatePanel>

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDrCode" runat="server" OnFocus="this.style.borderColor='red'" OnBlur="this.style.borderColor=''"></asp:TextBox>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

---

```
Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Protected Sub chkNotKnown_CheckedChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkNotKnown.CheckedChanged
        With txtDrCode
            If chkNotKnown.Checked Then
                .Text = "Not Known"
                .Enabled = False
            Else
                .Text = ""
                .Enabled = True
            End If
        End With
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `chkNotKnown` is inside the UpdatePanel, while `txtDrCode` is outside of it. Also you specify `chkNotKnown` as an `asyncPostBackTrigger`, which is the same as something already present in the UpdatePanel.

So either change the Trigger to a `PostBackTrigger` (causing a full PostBack)

```
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="chkNotKnown" />
</Triggers>
```

Or place the TextBox inside the UpdatePanel

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel_1">
    <ContentTemplate>

        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkNotKnown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
            Text="(Not Known)" OnCheckedChanged="chkNotKnown_CheckedChanged" />

        <asp:TextBox ID="txtDrCode" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```